# Animate dynamic textblock for announcement

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, expression-blend, textblock

In expression blend 4, is it a way to animate a textblock content like a slide animation from bottom to top until the content is finish? The content of the textblock is dynamic, which is can be short or long content. Short content will not animate anything, but long content will do. Anyone knows how to do this? A link maybe?

Comment: show some code, what and how you've tried.

Comment: No code. Just doing animation like the closing film casting,director,special thanks etc. Going from bottom to top. I don't have code because I want to think the logic first

Comment: I suggest you to invest some effort into same, then ask if you feel blocked. Then the community would me more happy to help you. you may please have a look at [ask]